# PINE64 - Failed to spawn window-stack-bridge main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory

Tags: 16.04, arm

Long time lurker but first time poster, hopefully the information below helps:

**Build:**

- Linux pine64 3.10.101-0-pine64-longsleep

**Actions Preformed:**

- Installed: OpenSSH
- fdisk to expand filesystem to full capacity
- Installed: Ubuntu-Desktop
- apt-get update && upgrade && clean all

So after all this, when the pine starts up the login screen appears, I add in the root password, it logs in the desktop mouse cursor shows for a second and the screen goes blank and goes back to the login screen.

[My .xsession-errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSJSZ.png)
Can't seem to find anything helpful on google about the missing file for window-stack-bridge, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I went with xfce4 and that booted to desktop without any issues. Proceeded to remove unity and everything so far has worked out.